# Growing Money Plant purely in Vermiculite

Tags: houseplants

Is it possible to grow money plant only in Vermiculite? The plant grows in soil and water, so can it grow only in vermiculite, as vermiculite retains water really well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without providing additional nutrients. Vermiculite is inert and contains negligible amounts of nutrients, and your plants would quickly show signs of nutrient deficiencies if provided with water alone. However, as a substrate in a hydroponics system where a nutrient solution is used, it can perform well although other substrates are more commonly used for economic reasons.

Comment: But wouldn't the plant get nutrients from the water containing vermiculite? Just like how it grows in water alone?

Comment: Pure water does not contain nutrients. A plant grown in pure water will eventually get deficiencies and die. Some plants can tolerate this for a surprisingly long time but ultimately plants require elements other than Hydrogen (from water), Carbon (from Carbon dioxide) and Oxygen (from both).

Comment: But my money plant is growing in water only. I am not giving anything else, except changing water every week.

Comment: It might appear healthy at present but if you are giving it pure water and nothing else it will in time show symptoms of deficiencies. Some plants can last a very long time in just water - very often they won't grow much or they will "remodel" themselves perhaps getting thinner as they get taller. Categorically, all plants contain more elements than just Hydrogen, Carbon and Oxygen (which they can get from the atmosphere and water). Generally, the other elements are absorbed by the roots from soil.